# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I think I have an error with my routing configuration and a controller but i dont know where specifically the error is coming from cus a new to mvc can somebody please help me the error am getting is..

> 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Int32, System.String)'
>   in 'OnlineShoppingStore.webUI.Controllers.CartController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter'

My cart controller (Addtocart) is-

```
  public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int productId, string returnUrl)
    {            
        Product product = repository.products.FirstOrDefault(p => 
         p.ProuductId == productId);
            if (product != null)
            {
                GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
            }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
     }
```

My route config is:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(null, "",
            new
            {
                Controller = "Product",
                action = "list",
                category=(string) null,
                page=1
            });
        routes.MapRoute(null, "Page{Page}",
            new
            {
                Controller = "Product",
                action = "list",
                category = (string)null
            },
         new { Page = @"\d+" });
        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Product",
                action = "list",
                Page = 1
            });
        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}/Page{Page}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Product",
                action = "list"
            },
            new { Page = @"\d+"});
        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");       
   }
```

Comment: How are you calling the `AddToCart()` method - and none of your routes contain a segment for `productId`.

Comment: Do you want me to show the full controller code? and i know it might be the routes segmrnt cus theres no productId in it ill appreciate if you can help with it or show how i can change it thanks...

Comment: The controller code has got nothing to so with it. Its how you generate the url for that method which is your problem - if you navigate to `/Cart/AddToCart?productId=1&returnUrl=xxx` it will work fine - but clearly you are not providing a query string value for `productId`

Comment: <div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.Price.ToString("c")</span>
    </h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
    {
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProuductId)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success " value="Add To Cart." />
        </div>
        <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
    }      
</div>
 i think??

Comment: Your form is making a POST, but you have shown a GET method (is it marked with the `[HttpPost]` attribute?

Comment: nope the form is not marked with the [HttpPost] attribute

Comment: You either need to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the **controller method**, or add `FormMethod.Get` in your `BeginForm()`

Comment: added the [HttpPost] to the method,  so how do i solve the null method issue??

Comment: It will not be `null` assuming your `ProuductId` property contains a value (inspect what `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProuductId) ` generates - in particular the `value` attribute)

Comment: Actually you appear to have a simple typo - `productId` is not `ProuductId`

Comment: its working now thanks, i changed productId to ProuductId...